# Keep getting dtypes as object when I want it to be date

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried different solutions on stack overflow, but no matter what I keep returning as object. Column is shown below. I would like output to not have time included.

CLOSE_DATE = 2018-07-13 01:04:16 (again no time)

```
df_support_HCM['CLOSE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_support_HCM['CLOSE_DATE']).dt.date
```

Comment: Does the 'CLOSE' column exist already when you perform the assignment?

Comment: No, I am creating a new column from the CLOSE_DATE. However, it is probably best to just keep it as 'CLOSE_DATE' since it would just mean another step of dropping 'CLOSE_DATE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close': pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01 01:04:16', periods=19), 'val':range(1,20)})^M
df['new_date'] = df['close'].dt.normalize()

df
                 close  val   new_date
0  2021-01-01 01:04:16    1 2021-01-01
1  2021-01-02 01:04:16    2 2021-01-02
2  2021-01-03 01:04:16    3 2021-01-03
3  2021-01-04 01:04:16    4 2021-01-04
4  2021-01-05 01:04:16    5 2021-01-05
5  2021-01-06 01:04:16    6 2021-01-06
6  2021-01-07 01:04:16    7 2021-01-07
7  2021-01-08 01:04:16    8 2021-01-08
8  2021-01-09 01:04:16    9 2021-01-09
9  2021-01-10 01:04:16   10 2021-01-10
10 2021-01-11 01:04:16   11 2021-01-11
11 2021-01-12 01:04:16   12 2021-01-12
12 2021-01-13 01:04:16   13 2021-01-13
13 2021-01-14 01:04:16   14 2021-01-14
14 2021-01-15 01:04:16   15 2021-01-15
15 2021-01-16 01:04:16   16 2021-01-16
16 2021-01-17 01:04:16   17 2021-01-17
17 2021-01-18 01:04:16   18 2021-01-18
18 2021-01-19 01:04:16   19 2021-01-19

df.dtypes

close       datetime64[ns]
val                  int64
new_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked!

Comment: You’re welcome. Please accept the answer if it’s don’t mind.